# JSF questions and advices

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm doing a JSF2 project. I use mojarra 2.x, PrimeFaces 2.2RC2, Tomcat 6.x and Google Guice.

1. For the moment I use commandlink to navigate through my site, so everytime I want to reload, the navigator ask for resubmit value. I see on the net that it's possible to redirect. Does it better to use outputlink or commandlink for navigation?
2. Many times I use action with parameter like this:

   ```
   <:commandlink action="#{bean.doSomething(item)}" />
   ```

   This is good or bad ?
3. Is there is some conventions in JSF for naming action, properties? Or what's your convention?
4. When I write a xhtml page, does it better to use only components or just when necessary ?

   Example

   ```
   #{bean.foo}
   ```

   or

   ```
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.foo}" />
   ```
5. What about the use of JSTL tags like `<c:if>` ? I use some because I had some problems when I use `<ui:fragment rendered="">` during restoring view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `<h:commandLink>` fires a POST request. This makes no sense for page-to-page navigation. It's not user friendly nor SEO friendly. Just use `<h:outputLink>`, `<h:link>` or even `<a>` which fires a plain HTTP GET request.
2. If `item` is already present in the instance behind `#{bean}` then this is unnecessary. If it's not, then it's perfectly fine. You only need to keep in mind that your code is this way not backwards compatible on Servlet 2.5 containers anymore while JSF 2.0 itself is backwards compatible on Servlet 2.5. It's namely a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 feature (I only wonder how you get it to run on Tomcat 6. Aren't you using Tomcat 7 or are you using JBoss EL?).
3. I wouldn't care that much, e.g. `ProductManager`, `ProductController`, `Products`, etc, as long as it is as much as possible self-documenting from the view side on. I.e. not `#{pc.submit}` or `#{pd.column1}`, but `#{products.find}` and `#{product.name}`.
4. In Facelets, both are equally valid. Both are XML-escaped. The `<h:outputText>` only has the advantage that it allows easy access by `UIViewRoot` and adding attributes like `styleClass`, `id`, `rendered`, etc.
5. As long as you use it only when you want to control how the view is built, not how view is rendered, then it's perfectly fine. Note that those `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core` tags are provided by Facelets itself, not by good ol' JSP JSTL JAR's (which has `/jsp` in taglib URI).

#### Related

- [When should I use `h:outputLink` instead of `h:commandLink`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723)
- [JSTL `c:if` inside JSF `h:dataTable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442380/jstl-cif-inside-a-jsf-hdatatable)

Comment: For the 2: item its for example <ui:repeat value="#{somelist}" var="item">. What is the other way to do the same and be compatible with backward ? I use org.glassfish.web EL.

Comment: Two ways: 1) supply `DataModel<E>` as value and grab it by `DataModel#getRowData()` inside action method. 2) pass it by `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951263/jsf-command-button-inside-a-jsf-data-table/3951281#3951281).