# Datatable with commandButton vs. Dynamic Button from String

Tags: jsf, button, dynamic, hyperlink, datatable

I am working on creating a button or link to add a product to a cart after someone searches for products.  Here is that section from our ProdcutsController.java class:

```
public String getResponse() {
    String resultStr = "";
    resultStr += theModel.getProductID() + "<br/>"
            + theModel.getUserID() + "<br/>"
            + theModel.getTitle() + "<br/>"
            + theModel.getProductType() + "<br/>"
            + theModel.getProductDesc() + "<br/>"
            + theModel.getRating() + "<br/>"
            + theModel.getPictureURL() + "<br/>"
            + theModel.getPrice() + "<br/>";

    response = resultStr;
    return response;
}

public String searchProduct() {
    ProductsDAO aProductDAO = new ProductsDAOImpl();    // Creating a new object each time.
    ArrayList products = aProductDAO.searchProduct(theModel); 

    response = "";

    for (int i=0; i < products.size(); i++) {
        theModel = (ProductsBean)products.get(i);
        response += getResponse();
    }
    theModel.setSearchResult(response);

    return "searchResults.xhtml"; // navigate to "searchResults.xhtml"
}
```

Right now it displays as bad as it looks.  I am pretty new to JSF (using version 2.1 in our course) and have used ASP.NET before for a similar course.  My original idea, which I think violated rule #2 in [BalusC's comment for "h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/2305667), was to add after the response += getResponse() the JSF code for a commandButton that invokes our method, addToCart() within the Products Controller.  It displays the buttons next to the respective search result, but does not run the #{cartController.addToCart()} method.

I looked into Data Tables like [BalusC's comment for "JSF Command button inside a JSF data Table"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951281/2305667).  Basically this boils down to two questions:

- Should we attempt data tables to display our data and use a "Add to Cart" button in a column?  Will I be able to bind this to the addToCart() method for that specific product ID?  I ask "should" because we are new to JSF, and this might be over our heads.
- Was my first solution workable?  Can we dynamically create workable JSF form buttons within a String from a ?
- Is there something simpler than what we were attempting?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  We are currently using JSF 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to implement the datatable looking at BalusC's comment above in the link I provided.  It worked beautifully and simply once we did some trial/error.